# Is it possible to automate data mining

Tags: data-science, data-mining, automated-machine-learning

I'm a Frontend Dev tasked with Data Insights (Help!) Hey everyone!

I'm a fresh graduate working as a front-end developer. This is my first real job, and I'm thrown into the deep end a bit! My first task is to figure out a way to automatically generate insights from a dataset.

The catch? It doesn't necessarily need to be super insightful, just something.

I'm coming from a pure front-end background, so data analysis is new territory for me. Any advice on how to approach this task would be greatly appreciated!

Here's what I know:

I need to work with a dataset related to schools (but I don't have details yet on the format or size). I need to automatically generate some kind of insights from the data. The "usefulness" of the insights isn't critical at this stage, I just need to generate a lot of insights and later decide if they are useful or not.

For example:-

there are 14 students whose name starts with A

there are 23 students that live in this area, etc

Here's what I'm hoping to learn:

Are there any common tools or libraries that can help with this task? What's a good starting point for exploring a dataset without any prior experience? Even if the insights aren't super deep, what are some basic things I could look for to demonstrate I'm on the right track? Thanks in advance for any help!